# How to stop light fittings on chain stop rotating

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, light

I have light fittings mounted on a single chain. I want them to stay at a certain angle but they keep rotating and I can't  get them to sit how I want.

How can I go about stopping them rotate? Thanks

Comment: Weld the links together. Or choose a more suitable support for your application.

Answer (score 2):

No pun intended but anchor the chain. You could replace the chain with a pole.

Since welding's not an option try a few drops of clear epoxy on each link when you get the chain into position.

Answer (score 2):

They are rotating to the rest position of the chain. Don't twist the chain once it gets there: it will only move back.

You need to set the head of the chain in such a position so that when it's at rest the business-end is where you want it.

So, if you usually move the lights say 60 degrees clockwise to put them in the "right" position, you need to move the ceiling fitting by that amount so the lights don't have to be moved. The chain will then rest where you want it to.

To do that, you might need a mounting plate like the ones shown in [this similar question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/77917/need-a-way-to-rotate-a-chandelier-without-rotating-its-mounting-point?rq=1). (I'm not sure this is actually a duplicate because the question is different, even though the solution is the same.)

If that's not possible, then follow [Ecnerwal's comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/192864/how-to-stop-light-fittings-on-chain-stop-rotating#comment341964_192864): Weld the links together. Or choose a more suitable support for your application.